# Are these actually "basis vectors?"

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image: Screen Shot]

From my understanding, basis vectors must span the entire space. For this particular question, Col $A$ is in the space $\mathbb{R}^3$, and Nul $A$ is in the space $\mathbb{R}^4$. Neither of these sets of vectors span those spaces. So, do we really consider them "basis" vectors? Or have I misunderstood the definition of basis vectors?

Comment: There's a difference between dimension of vector space and a dimension of a nvector.

Comment: @Mann -- are they considered basis vectors because they span the column space and null space, not necessarily R^3 and R^4 ?

Comment: Well to be precise, the definition of dimension of a vector space is the number of linearly independent vector spanning that space that's all. The element of that vector space could be anything, it may not even be a vector.

Comment: So if you are checking the basis for your column space simply try take $c_1v_1+c_2v_2$ and check that you can actually have finite solution of $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that you can obtain all other elements. Test it on column space for instance, assuming the answers are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that a basis $\color{red}{\text{of}\,\,\mathbb{R}^3}$ requires three vectors and a basis $\color{red}{\text{of}\,\,\mathbb{R}^4}$ requires four vectors. (Not just *any* three or four vectors, of course: the vectors have to be linearly independent and span the space.)

But the question does not ask for a basis of *these* spaces. It asks instead for bases of other vector spaces, namely the $\color{red}{\text{column space of $A$}}$ and the $\color{red}{\text{null space of $A$}}$. As you say, these are *subspaces* of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$, respectively. That means a basis for $\text{Col}\,A$ *may* have up to three vectors, but it may have fewer than three vectors, depending on $A$. Similarly, a basis for $\text{Null}\,A$ may have up to four vectors, but it may have fewer than four vectors, depending on $A$. You must use the row-reduced form of $A$ to determine the dimensions of these subspaces (as well as basis for them).

You can see the row-reduced form of $A$ has two pivots, so the dimension of $\text{Col}\,A$ is two. Hence a basis for $\text{Col}\,A$ will contain precisely two linearly independent vectors. (And indeed, the answer gives a basis with two vectors in it!) Do you know how to find two such vectors, given the information in the problem?

You can determine the dimension of the null space in several ways. Perhaps you know the "rank-nullity theorem," which says the dimension of the column space plus the dimension of the null space is the number of columns of $A$. We just found the dimension of $\text{Col}\,A$ is two, and $A$ has four columns, so the dimension of the null space is also two. So a basis for $\text{Null}\,A$ will contain precisely two linearly independent vectors. (And indeed, the answer gives a basis with two vectors in it.) Do you know how to find two such vectors, given the information in the problem?

Comment: Thank you for this! This course is only offered online, and I want to make sure I'm understanding everything correctly. Those answers are mine, and I understand how I arrived at them. I was just a little confused on the vocabulary. Once again, a million thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The rank of $A$ is $2$. $A$ takes vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ to a $2$-dimensional subset (a plane) in $\mathbb R^3$.

And that means that there is a $2$-dimensional subset of $\mathbb R^4$ that gets mapped to $0$ (the kernel).

You have two basis vectors that span the image.  And you have two basis vectors that span the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

A basis **for $V$** must span $V$. The vector space $V$ might be a subspace of some bigger vector space $W$.  If $V$ is not all of $W$, the basis should not span $W$.  So in your first example $\text{Col}\ A$ is contained in $\mathbb R^3$ but is not all of it, and it's perfectly fine to have a basis for $\text{Col}\ A$ consisting of two vectors, spanning $\text{Col}\ A$ but not all of $\mathbb R^3$.